# Qt QMenu setting a stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMenu which I create like this.

```
QMenu *logoMenu = new QMenu();
```

I then add it to a QToolButton like so

```
logoButton->setMenu(logoMenu);
```

now I have an project.qss file which has the following stylesheet for the QMenu

```
QMenu#logoMenu {
     background-color: #161614; /* sets background of the menu */
     border: 0px solid #161614;
     width: 150px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
 }

 QMenu::item#logoMenu {  
     background-color: transparent;
 }

 QMenu::item:selected#logoMenu { 
     background-color: #202020;
 }
```

My problem is that the stylesheet does NOT get applies to the QMenu, I know I am loading the stylesheet correctly because I can style other widgets.

If I set the stylesheet manually like so

```
logoMenu->setStyleSheet("QMenu {.....}");
```

Here is how I create the QMenu:

```
logoMenu        = new QMenu();
logoMenu->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Import"));
logoMenu->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Export"));
logoMenu->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Help"));
logoMenu->addAction(QString::fromUtf8("Exit"));
logoMenu->setObjectName("logoMenu");
```

It works, no problem. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I think you need to style menu, instead of menubar. apply style sheet from QMenubar to QMenu::~~.objectName..

Comment: Ahh, sorry. My mistake, I will make an edit.  I tried it with QMenu and it still did not work.

Comment: try logoMenu->setObjectName( "logoMenu" );

Answer (score 1):

Your Id selector is QMenu#logoMenu

> It means  Matches all "QMenu" instances whose object name is
>   "logoMenu". So you need to set object name of QMenu(
>   yourMenu->setObjectName( "logoMenu" ) )

Note:If QMenu is created using ui designer, Ui compiler will generate the code for yourMenu->setObjectName( "logoMenu" ). But if you are creating your own QMenu, you need to set object name explicitly to work your style type.

Comment: Comment all other style in stylesheet except QMenu and try

Comment: still does not want to style... :/

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments under [Ashifs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18669156/7136013) you are missing a connection inside your Qt object tree. Try instantiating your QMenu with a parent that has a connection to the stylesheet. Probably just:

```
QMenu *logoMenu = new QMenu(this);
```

Alternatively you can set your stylesheet application global by adding it to the QApplication instance:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("...");
```